# Как вызвать метод контроллера в ASP.NET через JS

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Имеется контроллер, который сортирует товары

```
public ViewResult Sort(string category, string subcategory,SortState sortState = SortState.IdAsc, int page = 1)
    {
        int tblID = -1;
        if (category != null && subcategory != null)
        {
            string tbid = sqlWorker.SelectDataFromDB("SELECT GoodTableID from GoodsTables Where CategoryID = (SELECT CategoryID FROM Categories Where Name = '" + category + "') and TableName = '" + subcategory + "'");
            if (tbid != null)
            {
                tblID = Convert.ToInt32(tbid);
            }
        }

        IEnumerable<Good> goods = repository.Goods;

        switch (sortState)
        {
            case SortState.IdAsc:
                {
                    goods = repository.Goods
                    .Where(good => tblID == -1 || good.TableID == tblID)
                    .OrderBy(good => good.GoodID)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize);
                    break;
                }
            case SortState.NameAsc:
                {
                    goods = repository.Goods
                    .Where(good => tblID == -1 || good.TableID == tblID)
                    .OrderBy(good => good.Name)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize);
                    break;
                }
            case SortState.NameDesc:
                {
                    goods = repository.Goods
                    .Where(good => tblID == -1 || good.TableID == tblID)
                    .OrderByDescending(good => good.Name)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize);
                    break;
                }
            case SortState.PriceAsc:
                {
                    goods = repository.Goods
                    .Where(good => tblID == -1 || good.TableID == tblID)
                    .OrderBy(good => good.Price)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize);
                    break;
                }
            case SortState.PriceDesc:
                {
                    goods = repository.Goods
                    .Where(good => tblID == -1 || good.TableID == tblID)
                    .OrderByDescending(good => good.Price)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize);
                    break;
                }
            case SortState.RatingAsc:
                {
                    goods = repository.Goods
                    .Where(good => tblID == -1 || good.TableID == tblID)
                    .OrderBy(good => good.Rating)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize);
                    break;
                }
            case SortState.RatingDesc:
                {
                    goods = repository.Goods
                    .Where(good => tblID == -1 || good.TableID == tblID)
                    .OrderByDescending(good => good.Rating)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize);
                    break;
                }
            case SortState.ViewsAsc:
                {
                    goods = repository.Goods
                    .Where(good => tblID == -1 || good.TableID == tblID)
                    .OrderBy(good => good.Views)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize);
                    break;
                }
            case SortState.ViewsDesc:
                {
                    goods = repository.Goods
                    .Where(good => tblID == -1 || good.TableID == tblID)
                    .OrderByDescending(good => good.Views)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize);
                    break;
                }
        }


        GoodViewModel model = new GoodViewModel
        {
            Goods = goods,

            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = pageSize,
                TotalItems =  repository.Goods.Count()
            },
            CurrentCategory = category,
            CurrentSubcategory = subcategory,
            SortState = sortState
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

Имеется представление

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <select name="one" class="dropdown-select" id="asc">
            <option value="IdAsc">Сортировка по ID</option>
            <option value="NameAsc">Сортировка по имени</option>
            <option value="PriceAsc">Сортировка по цене</option>
            <option value="ViewsAsc">Сортировка по кол-ву просмотров</option>
            <option value="RatingAsc">Сортировка по рейтингу</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

И соответсвенно скрипт, который должен обрабатывать сортировку, т.е. вызывать метод контроллера /Good/Sort

```
function Sort(sortState) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: '@Url.Action("Sort","Good")',
        data: { sortState: sortState }
    }).done(function () {
        alert('Sorted');
    });
}


$('#asc').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "NameAsc") {
            Sort("NameAsc")
        }
    })
```

С параметром sortState, который указывает, по какому полю будет произведена сортировка.
В итоге при выборе из selec-option срабатывает только

```
}).done(function () {
    alert('Sorted');
});
```

А часть, которая приведена ниже, нет.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: '@Url.Action("Sort","Good")',
        data: { sortState: sortState }
```

Буду очень благодарен, если подскажете, что не так. Как вызвать здесь метод Sort контроллера GoodController с параметром sortState. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Метод Sort отработал, запрос вернул некоторые данные. Но эти данные никак не используются в js.

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы всё же выполнялся метод контроллера при выборе элемента из select?